# Large geospatial join usign BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, geometry, geospatial, polygon

I'm using a large table in BigQuery with a geometry column and nested fields.

The query is as follows:

```
WITH
  temp_01 AS(
  SELECT
    id,
    geometry,
    mle.metadata.localId AS localId,
  FROM `dataset.maps_layer` mle
  WHERE layer_id = 4 )
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,  temp_02 AS (
  SELECT
    metadata.localId AS localId,
    geometry,
  FROM `dataset.maps_layer` mle
  WHERE  layer_id = 1 ) --buildings
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

select * from temp_01 p
LEFT JOIN temp_02 b ON (ST_INTERSECTS(b.geometry, p.geometry)) 
WHERE b.localId IS NULL
```

The geometry column contains Polygons and MultiPolygons and, temp_02 can be polygons within the polygons in temp_01. The thing is that I'm trying to figure out how to perform a join that results in a table where temp_01 has no polygons inside (that's the `localId` condition in the `WHERE` clause).

With a smaller table, this query won't be an issue. However, this query will process 61.73 GB when run and takes more than 6h (so it finish without result).

Is there any other spatial function that could improve the performance of the join? I've been trying to use `ST_CENTROID` to maybe, make a filter of it. Or even, use the `ST_BOUNDINBOX` as a limit. However, I've seen no improvement. Additionally, the polygons stored are relatively simply (rectangles, pentagons and hexagons).

Any feedback would be really appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I replaced the JOIN columns with a hash made out of the `localId` (as it has to be the same for both types of polygons.

Ultimately, the latest join I have to make after the one I showed in my question, It's solved using a geohash as keys.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery only [optimized spatial inner join](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data#using_joins_with_spatial_data), not left/right outer join, which is most likely why the query is so slow.

So what I would do is

1. inner spatial join to find ids that do have spatial match, it should be much faster,
2. then regular left join to eliminate such ids,

Something like

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM temp_01 p
LEFT JOIN (
  -- find all temp_01.id that do have a match
  select a.id 
  from temp_01 a 
  join temp_02 b 
    ON ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry, b.geometry)
  group by 1
) c
  ON p.id = c.id
-- then filter out the matches
WHERE c.id IS NULL
```